# How to create a 2D collider for a character in the game so that the character does not get stuck and does not fall?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a character in my 2d platformer game. The character must:

1. move on rectangular platforms and not "fall" (slide off) while standing on the edge.
2. move on an inclined plane.

But there is a problem.
It cannot be done at the same time. And the problem here is the collider.

If I make a 2d rectangular collider - the character does not fall (does not slide down from the edge) while standing on the edge of the platform. And this is good.
But the rectangular collider does not allow it to move on an inclined plane. And that's bad.

If I make a 2d collider capsule, the character slides down from the edge, standing on the edge of the platform. And that's bad.
But the collider capsule allows it to move on an inclined plane. And this is good.

What to do?

[image]

Tried various colliders and their combinations - did not help.

Comment: I never had an issue using a rectangular collider for my characters for angles up to about 45°. The physics system should be detecting the collider intersection and pushing out your character in the direction of the ground normal, slowly raising your height. Show your controller code and make sure to add a language tag, like c#, so you get a bigger response.

Comment: I think the built-in dynamic physics are not well suited for platformer games. What I do (especially for player character) is use kinematic Rigidbody2D with raycasting (that proximates rectangular collider) and "manually" control the Rigidbody2D velocity from FixedUpdate method.

Comment: I recorded a short video showing the problem.
https://youtu.be/Liv75ab_oLk  As you can see, there is a 45 degree angle.  Here is my player controller code 

    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
    Vector3 movement = new Vector2(horizontalInput * playerSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    rb.velocity = movement;

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are facing isn't caused by the collider of your character, but rather the collider of the tilemap. As you have displayed in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Liv75ab_oLk) the 45° ramps aren't perfectly smooth, but have hard 90° steps in them. Obviously a rectangular collider will get caught in them, preventing further movement.

To fix your issue you need to configure the "physics shape" of the ramp sprite to create a [Custom Physics Shape](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPhysicsShape.html).

1. select your tilemap sprite in the assets
2. open the `Sprite Editor`
3. switch the drop down in the top left from `Sprite Editor` to `Custom Physics Shape`
4. select the ramp sprite tile
5. adjust the shape so that it becomes a triangle that smoothly goes from corner to corner

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This partially solves the problem. Now the player with the box collider can climb up an inclined surface. But it gets stuck on a flat surface.
I did not write this earlier, because I did not observe this in my previous tests.

In the video you can see how the player's movement is interrupted for a second. But I press the keys. The player gets stuck on a flat surface.
https://youtu.be/TPAnzULxfYI

I'm a little wary of using the box collider because the slightest protrusion will cause the player to get stuck.

Comment: @Иван the BoxCollider2D has a [`edgeRadius`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D-edgeRadius.html) atribute. If it is greater than zero the box will have rounded edges that should deal with slight bumps.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. I know about this box collider feature. It won't help.
If the collider has any rounding, the player will slide off the edge. It is obvious. If there is no rounding, i.e. boxing, the player will get stuck.

I found a solution to my problem - changing colliders. The player runs = capsule, the player stands = box. But there is a little strange behavior here (perhaps this is a feature of the physics engine).
I'll write this in another question.